# Give journaltitle instead of title in citations when there is no author

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I have to cite a few articles that have no author and I want to alter how that is done in biblatex-chicago author-date style.

According to the new Chicago rules, when you cite a book without author, instead of using "Anonymous" you just give the title and date. For articles, this is implemented in biblatex-chicago so that it gives the article title, but I would rather give the journal title instead. Now biblatex-chicago does give the journal title if you change the entrysubtype to magazine (unlike regular biblatex), but in that case the volume number disappears in the references. How do I change it so that I can get the journaltitle instead of the article title and still retain the volume in the references?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Science1936a,
    title        = {The Harvard Tercentenary},
    date         = {1936},
    journaltitle = {Science},
    volume       = {83},
    pages        = {566--567},
    number       = {2163}
}
@Article{Science1936b,
    title        = {The Harvard Tercentenary},
    date         = {1936},
    journaltitle = {Science},
    volume       = {83},
    pages        = {566--567},
    number       = {2163},
    entrysubtype = {magazine}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    As journal subtype: \cite{Science1936a}\\       
    As magazine subtype: \cite{Science1936b}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The desired outcome for the citation would be:

> *Science* 1936

and for the reference section:

> *Science*. 1936. "The Harvard Tercentenary." Vol. 83 (2163): 566-567.

so including the added `Vol.` before the volume.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I worked around the problem for now by entering the journal as author and adding Vol. to the volume. It works well but its not really elegant and would be a problem if I ever change styles.